# How to make Google Search results show these links for my website?

Tags: google-search, search-results, sitelinks

Does anyone know how to get my Google results as below?

Are there any specific rules I have to follow like microdata, etc. ?

[image: Google Search results for ‘buy bed covers online’]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are referring to here is sitelinks, see below:

> Sitelinks are hyperlinks to website subpages that appear under certain
>   Google listings in order to help users navigate the site. The site
>   owner cannot add any sitelinks; Google adds them through its own
>   secret automated algorithms.If you have a Google Adwords program you
>   can create campaign and adgroup level sitelinks.

Source:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitelink

Edit - Additional info on 'Mini Sitelinks'

**MINI SITELINKS**

> Mini sitelinks have now become much more common than the traditional
>   variety. As their alternative name (one-line sitelinks) suggests these
>   are all displayed on one line, and there are usually four of them.
>   There can even be more than one set of them for a particular search
>   term. Quite a number of search results that do not make it to number
>   one in the search list still qualify to have a row of mini sitelinks
>   placed on them.
>
> The key differences between the two types of sitelinks are:
>
> - Sitelinks seem to be (generally) limited to branded searches,    although the mini sitelinks are not
> - Sitelinks only appear beside the    number one result in a search, but mini sitelinks can appear beside    lower ranked results
> - Mini sitelinks can appear beside multiple search    results for a term
> - It is even possible for a particular domain to    appear more than once in a search of a specified term, and there can    actually be
>     different mini sitelinks on the different appearances of    that site
>     in the results. A particular domain can even show with    traditional
>     sitelinks at the top of a search, but with mini sitelinks    further
>     down the results.

Source: http://www.datadial.net/blog/all-you-need-to-know-about-google-sitelinks-and-mini-sitelinks/